# MoveIt add collision box coordinates system understanding

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

Anyone can help me understanding moveIt coordinates system while adding collisions. I am attaching the code and I want an understanding of one lines.

Src of code : Moveit tutorials : moveit_tutorials/doc/collision_environments/scripts/collision_scene_example.py

```
from __future__ import print_function

import rospy
from moveit_commander import RobotCommander, PlanningSceneInterface
import geometry_msgs.msg
import time
import sys

class CollisionSceneExample(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._scene = PlanningSceneInterface()

        # clear the scene
        self._scene.remove_world_object()

        self.robot = RobotCommander()

        # pause to wait for rviz to load
        print("============ Waiting while RVIZ displays the scene with obstacles...")

        # TODO: need to replace this sleep by explicitly waiting for the scene to be updated.
        rospy.sleep(2)

    def add_one_box(self):
        box1_pose = [0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
        box1_dimensions = [0.25, 0.25, 0.75]

        self.add_box_object("box1", box1_dimensions, box1_pose)
```

I want the explanation of below line:

```
        box1_pose = [0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 1]  # Over here arg_1 = X pos, arg_2 = Y pos, arg_3 = Z pos, What about others?
```

Thanks for helping!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375190/moveit-add-collision-box-coordinates-system-understanding/) by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1622 on 2021-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-02**:\

> Closed for the following reason spam or advertising

I doubt this is "spam or advertising".

In addition, we don't close questions here on ROS Answers when they've been *answered*.

Simply click on the checkmark of the answer you feel best answers your question. It will turn green, and will clearly mark the question as answered.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-04-02**:
Actually, this question was silly. I have not seen a proper code and posted a question, that was the reason for closing this question.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-04-02**:
I understand, but that's how Q&A sites work. It's rare that someone is the only one to have a question, and hopefully the next person who has this one will google it and find it answered for them.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-04-02**:
Okay! understood and thanks for the help! @gvdhroom and @fvd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The function `add_box_object` is defined further down in the same file, and it shows that those are the quaternion components that define the orientation:

```
def add_box_object(self, name, dimensions, pose):
    p = geometry_msgs.msg.PoseStamped()
    p.header.frame_id = self.robot.get_planning_frame()
    p.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    p.pose.position.x = pose[0]
    p.pose.position.y = pose[1]
    p.pose.position.z = pose[2]
    p.pose.orientation.x = pose[3]
    p.pose.orientation.y = pose[4]
    p.pose.orientation.z = pose[5]
    p.pose.orientation.w = pose[6]
```

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-04-01**:
Sorry! for the silly question. How can I forget that. Omg! Really have to take a rest. Haha

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-04-01**:
Thanks for helping!

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-04-01**:
Can I close this question? I don't think it will be helpful